# how to export and import nodes in bulk?

Tags: nodes

is there any way to export and import nodes programmatically...? While import if the node already exists then it should be updated without creating a new node.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Node Export](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_export) module

> This module allows users to export nodes and then import it into another Drupal installation, or on the same site.
>
> Using this module you can save yourself a lot of time setting up new websites that have similar nodes to websites you've already made, migrating nodes to new Drupal versions, or between development/staging/production sites.
>
> You will need the same content types for the imports to work (unless using Feeds to import), and ideally relevant compatibility with fields, and modules

Comment: i used that module but it creates duplicate nodes.

Comment: i also tried by changing the node export settings to " Create a new revision of the existing node "

Comment: @Mukil things you already tried should be in question. It's a waste of time to guess what you tried, or to provide you answers you know won't work for you.

Comment: @Mukil that's not *my* tip. Please read [Help Center / Asking](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/asking).

Comment: @Mukil that's exactly why you should read Help Center. Everyone needed to do it when they, well, when WE was noobs.

Comment: @KrishnaMohan it should update the node instead of skipping it.

Comment: @KrishnaMohan I tried it, but it continues to duplicate the node.

Comment: Node Export does NOT work. You import into a Drupal 9 site and nothing happens. It just ignores it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll most likely want to use

- the [Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate) module ([documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/415260)) or
- the [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) module ([documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/622696)).

I haven't used either myself, so I can't be of much more help. But I believe they can both be used to import data, and update nodes if they already exist.